# Java - UDP and Multicast detection

Tags: java, tcp, udp, multicast

On a single port I want to listen for Multicast, UDP, and TCP traffic. (on my LAN)
I also want to respond via UDP, if something is detected.

The code works below, but only for Multicast detection.  The while(true) loop is definitely doing it just, from the main().

But I'm running into a wall with adding another protocol detection method.
Can a single application have multiple sockets open, in multiple protocols?
I'm sure it's my limited knowledge of threading, but maybe someone can see my hiccup below.

```
public class LANPortSniffer  {

  private static void autoSendResponse() throws IOException {

     String sentenceToSend = "I've detected your traffic";
     int PortNum = 1234;

     DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
     InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.121");
     byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];

     sendData = sentenceToSend.getBytes();
     DatagramPacket sendPacket = 
       new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, PortNum);
     clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
     clientSocket.close();


  }//eof autoSendResponse


  private static void MulticastListener() throws UnknownHostException {

     final InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName("224.0.0.0");
     final int port = 1234;

     try {

       System.out.println("multi-cast listener is started......"); 
       MulticastSocket socket = new MulticastSocket(port);
       socket.setInterface(InetAddress.getLocalHost());
       socket.joinGroup(group);

       byte[] buffer = new byte[10*1024];

       DatagramPacket data = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);

       while (true) {
          socket.receive(data);

           // auto-send response
           autoSendResponse();

       }


      } catch (IOException e) {
         System.out.println(e.toString());
      }

  }//eof MulticastListener

// this method is not even getting launched
private static void UDPListener() throws Exception {

    DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(1234);
    byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];

    System.out.println("UDP listener is started......"); 
    while(true)
       {
          DatagramPacket receivePacket = 
                new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
          serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
          String sentence = new String( receivePacket.getData());
          System.out.println("UDP RECEIVED: " + sentence);

       }    

}



    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
            //creating and showing this application's GUI.
            javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    createAndShowGUI(); 
                }
             });


            try {
            MulticastListener();

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }


           // this does not appear to be detected:
            try {
            UDPListener();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}//eof LANPortSniffer
```

In main(), I tried adding a second try/catch, for a simple UDPListener() method.
But it seems to be ignored when I run the application in Eclipse.

Does the main() method only allow for one try/catch?

In a nutshell, I'd like to listen on a single port for Multicast, UDP, and TCP packets all at the same time. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your getting into a Threading issue here. I think you need to brush up on understanding of Java. When you call `MulticastListener()` it will never leave that block until your connection fails. It has a continous while loop. You need to create a new Thread for each of these activities.

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() { 
   public void run() {
         MulticastListener();
   }
}
t.start();
```

However I recommend you read up on your understanding of the programs flow and use of a more object orientated approach before you start trying to implement a threaded program.

Answer (score 0):

1)  You'll need raw socket access, which you won't get with a MulticastListener.
2)  Look-up Promiscuous Mode and Raw Sockets in Java.
3)  Threading issues are irrelevant - they will only give you better reactive performance - suggest you get it working with one thread before you improve your code.